# Linear transformation exercise doubt

Tags: linear-algebra

> In Exercises 1 to 8 a formula is given for a function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$. In each exercise determine if $F$ is linear.
>
> 2.(x^2,y), the solution states is none linear.

My answer: given the definition a transformantion is linear if  $1)\:T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)\:\:\text{and}\:\:2)\:\:T(ku)=kT(u)$. I feel compeled to answer this way:
$(x^2+h^2,y+z)=(x^2,y)+(h^2,z)$ so 1) is satisfied and $(kx^2,ky)=k(x^2,y),\forall k\in\mathbb{R}$ so 2) is satisfied. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes instead of $(x^2+h^2,y+z)=(x^2,y)+(h^2,z)$ it should be $((x+h)^2,y+z))\not = (x^2,y)+(h^2,z)$. (your brackets are missing)

Comment: the map is defined by $T(x,y)=(x^2,y_1+y_2)$, then $$T(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)=((x_1+x_2)^2,y_1+y_2)\neq (x_1^2,y_1)+(x_2^2,y_2)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T $ is not linear since

\begin{align}
T\Bigl ((x,y)+(h,z)\Bigr)&=T\Bigl ((x+h,y+z)\Bigr) \\
&=\Bigl((x+h)^2,y+z\Bigr)\\
&=(x^2+h^2+2hx,y+z) \\
&=(x^2,y)+(h^2,z)+(2hx,0) \\
&=T (x,y)+T (h,z)+(2hx,0) \\
&\ne T (x,y)+T (h,z)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

In your question $T(x,y)=2.(x^2,y)=(2x^2,2y)$ but in your answer, you use $T(x,y)=(x^2,y)$.

Case $1: T(x,y)=2.(x^2,y)=(2x^2,2y)$
$$T(2,0)=(8,0)\\
2T(1,0)=2(2,0)=(4,0)\neq T(2,0)$$

Case $2: T(x,y)=(x^2,y)$

$$T(2,0)=(4,0)\\
2T(1,0)=2(1,0)=(2,0)\neq T(2,0)$$

So, it is not a linear transformation in either case.